# Selecting a different parent in Family Safety filters for Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, parental-controls

I've got Family Safety up and running nicely on a Windows 8 Surface, with two parent accounts and two child accounts.

When one of the child accounts reaches its time limit, the user can "Ask a parent for more time". However, the next dialog doesn't allow the parents to choose which parent account to use - it always comes up with my account, and my wife can't log in to authorise.

How can I allow the her account to allow more time/authorise sites etc?

She can use the same Live login on our Windows 7 computers to control these settings, and is listed as a Parent on the Family Safety website.

Comment: Why don't you have a single account you both know the information too for only this purpose?  Windows RT isn't Windows 7 lots changed in Family Safety with Windows 8/Windows RT

Comment: I imagine there is a method... creating more accounts is just a workaround.

Comment: are you both administrators ? also as far as i can tell, it will use whichever account you used to set up the family safety for that user.

Comment: TaylorGibb - That seems to be the Key - only my account is an administrator. @Ramhound - I could indeed make a single account that we both know the password too for this, but then that would clutter up my start screen/logins dropdown, etc. There's definitely an argument to creating a single "admin" user account and demoting mine down to a standard user, but there's also the issue of "yet another password to remember" that I don't like or want.

Comment: A single account would defeat the point of it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly this problem and after much fiddling, the answer is to make sure that your second parent is also set up as an **Administrator User** on each machine, you will then get the choice of either parent at the family safety prompts.

Even if they are set up as a parent they will not be prompted as a Standard User.